# Why is $\| x\| _1\leq n\| x\| _{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, normed-spaces

I am trying to show that $\| x\| _1\leq n\| x\| _{\infty}$. Here, we define $$\| x\| _1=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j| \ \ \text{and} \ \ \| x\| _{\infty}=\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |x_j|.$$ I am having difficulty proving this inequality, as I don't understand how the sum of all components of a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ can be less than $n$ times the largest component in absolute value.

To me, this seem very intuitive. The sum of all components must be greater than the single largest component.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Julian. $|x_i|\le m:=\max_i (|x_i|)$, $1\le i \le n$. $|x_1|+|x_2|+...\le m +m+......(n-times)$.

Comment: I agree that $$|x_1|+|x_2|+..+|x_n|<\max|x_1|+\max|x_2|+..+\max|x_n|,$$ but I think it's a problem in understanding the notation. For the infinity-norm $\|x\|_{\infty}$, doesn't this equal the single largest component (in absolute value)? I don't see how taking the maximum of each component makes much sense, e.g. $|3|+|4|=\max |3|+\max |4|$.

Comment: What would $\max|3|$ even mean here?

Comment: Julian. Your right hand : Max |x_1|=|x_1|, Max |x_2|=|x_2|..Consider |x_1|,|x_2|..|x_k|,..take the max of these numbers, the largest one of them.

Comment: @ClementYung I thought we had to take the maximum of each individual component, i.e. every $x_j$ for $1\leq j\leq n$. This is so very incorrect lol

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yep, I understand now. This makes sense. If we take $\max\{|x_1|,|x_2|,..,|x_n|\}$ and denote this value as $|x_p|$ for some $1\leq p\leq n$, then clearly $$|x_1|+|x_2|+..+|x_n|\leq n|x_p|.$$

Comment: Julian.Yes!!Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

$\begin{align*}
  \| x \|_1
     &=   \sum_{1 \le k \le n}
                 \lvert x_k \rvert \\
     &\le \sum_{1 \le k \le n}
                \| x \|_\infty \\
     &=    n \| x_k \|_\infty
\end{align*}$

Second step is from the definition as the maximum of the $x_k$.

Comment: How can we assume that $|x_1|>|x_2|$ and $|x_1|>|x_3|$?

Comment: Because I have assumed that the maximum component of $x$ is $x_1$. If that is not the case, you can reorder the components of the vector without changing the value of either norm, so if the maximum were $|x_p|$ for some $p$, I can just reorder to make it $|x_1|$.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I think I get it. Crap. So for the general case, $|x_1|+|x_2|+..+|x_n|\leq n|x_p|$ for $1\leq p\leq n$, where $|x_p|=\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |x_j|$ ??

Comment: Absolutely correct. You got it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I don't know what was happening upstairs haha